# Stenography (Plover) integration

Tags: word-processing, input-methods, input-devices

I use Vim for academic writing and my preferred writing method is using stenography with [Plover](http://www.openstenoproject.org/plover/).

Is there any initiative to integrate Stenography/Plover into Vim? Currently, I am switching keyboards to change from Writing to Editing in Vim. This works, but requires heavy hacking (building and programming the keyboards with QMK).

Stuff like looking up words, managing input devices and Plover plugins are only available using a Qt-GUI...

Comment: This site uses markdown for Q&A, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. This question does seem a bit broad to me: the answer is either "yes there is some initiative" or "no there isn't"—neither of which seem very helpful? Perhaps you could describe your goal, what you've tried, what problems there are, etc. I also find the hyperbole in the first two sentences off-putting, particularly as the first link has nothing to do with the idea in the attached sentence. You should probably also continue to mention your affiliation with PS to avoid being marked as spam.

Comment: I find there's a potentially very interesting question here. But unfortunately I don't know much about stenography to be able to tell... I'd love it if you could expand to explain a bit how stenography works (at a glance) and what's challenging about using it with Vim. (For example, why typing `d4w` or `ggVGgU` or `:%s/\(\s\+\)/\1\1/g` would be challenging on a stenography setup.)

Comment: For instance, Vim has features that can help with using a Dvorak or Colemak keyboard layout only during insertion, while going back to Qwerty during command mode (see help for `'keymap'`, `'langmap'`, `:lmap`, `mapmode-l`, etc.) Would those help in supporting a stenography setup in some way? Also, it seems that Plover is Python code. Vim can call into Python code. I can see a way to map every key in Insert mode and have the mappings call a Python function that could call into Plover... Did you try asking this question at the Plover project? They know about stenography more than we do...

Comment: Steno it very different from other keyboard layouts.  Please have a look at the following clips to get an idea: General intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpv-Qb-dB6g Plover and Vim for real-time captioning: http://plover.stenoknight.com/2014/11/captioning-with-plover-and-vim.html

Comment: There are things like https://github.com/Josiah-tan/plover-vim . The question about lookup with qt GUI is unrelated but you can just stroke TKUPT to open up the "add translation" dialog then from that you can look up a word with the keyboard only.